# UISplitViewController with drop shadow possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, shadow

Using a `UISplitViewController`, I am trying to achieve an effect like this:

[image: splitview with drop shadow detail...]

Is this possible while using a `UISplitViewController`? I am not seeing any way to have a detail view cast a shadow on the `rootView`...

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I decided to abandon UISplitView in favor of [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController).  This allows for the flexibility I am looking for...